# If statement in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, if-statement

I want to write a basic if statement on my site to display either item 1 or item 2 depending on if a variable is set to true.

I'm not too familiar with .NET and need a little help with the basic structure of how to get an if statement to work on the aspx page

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/If-Else-statement-in-webforms-aspx-page

Answer (score 218, accepted):

if the purpose is to show or hide a part of the page then you can do the following things

1) wrap it in markup with

```
<% if(somecondition) { %>
   some html
<% } %>
```

2) Wrap the parts in a Panel control and in codebehind use the if statement to set the Visible property of the Panel.

Comment: XIII i want to checked a radio button if some variable is true, how to do it .?

Comment: sample code is 
 <input type="radio" id="Accept" name="optpost" value="1" <% if(item.Accept == 1){  checked="checked" }%>  class="Default" />

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. this is my code `<% if (false)
                                                       { %>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Quantity")).ToString("#####0") + " " + Eval("unitMsr") %>'>></asp:Label>
                                                    <% } %>` but it still show

Comment: @JohnNguyen Can you create a new question for this and make up the code in a more readable fashion?

Comment: @JohnNguyen It's because your markups is broken, in the end, here:  %>'>></asp:Label>
It's one > to much. Hope this hasen't been bothering your for 3 years xD

Comment: How can we do it with a single line?

Comment: @AkalankaEkanayake you should be able to write it in one line. Nowadays I would suggest to make use of Razor syntax when going for MVC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 47):

Just use simple code

```
<%
if(condition)
{%>

html code

<% } 
else 
{
%>
html code
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 10):

Normally you'd just stick the code in `Page_Load` in your `.aspx` page's code-behind.

```
if (someVar) {
    Item1.Visible = true;
    Item2.Visible = false;
} else {
    Item1.Visible = false;
    Item2.Visible = true;
}
```

This assumes you've got `Item1` and `Item2` laid out on the page already.

Comment: I concur with Daniel DiPaolo on how best to handle a toggled ASP.NET page display item based upon a true / false variable.

Answer (score 7):

A complete answer for optional content in the header of a VB.NET aspx page using a master page:

```
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="some_vb_page.aspx.vb" Inherits="some_vb_page" %> 
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">          
     <% If Request.QueryString("id_query_param") = 123 Then 'Add some VB comment here, 
         'which will not be visible in the rendered source code of the aspx page later %>        
         <!-- add some html content depending on -->
         <!-- the condition in the if statement: -->                
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <% End If %>
</asp:Content>
```

Where your current page url is something like:

http://mywebpage.com/some_vb_page.aspx?id_query_param=123

Answer (score 3):

```
<div>
    <% 
        if (true)
        {
    %>
    <div>
        Show true content
    </div>
    <%
        }
        else
        {
    %>
    <div>
        Show false content
    </div>
    <%
        }
    %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To use C# (C# Script was initialized at 2015)  on ASPX page you can make use the following syntax.

Start Tag:- `<%`
End tag:- `%>`
Please make sure that all the C# code must reside inside this `<%%>` .

Syntax Example:-

- `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>`  (For importing Namespace)
  Reference to some basic namespaces for working with ASPX page.

  `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
  <%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>
  <%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
  <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
  <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
  <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>`

C# Code:-

```
`<%
if (Session["New"] != null)
{
    Page.Title = ActionController.GetName(Session["New"].ToString());
}
%>`
```

Features of C# Script:

- No need of compilation. Run time execution is occurred like Java Script.

Before using C# script make sure the following things:-

- You are on WebForm. Not on WebForm with master page.
- If you are in WebForm with master page make sure that you have written your C# script at Master page file.
- C# script can be inserted anywhere in the aspx page but after the page meta declaration like

  `<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Profile.master.cs" Inherits="OOSDDemo.Profile" %>`

  `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>` (For WebForm)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple one written in VB for an ASPX page:

```
                If myVar > 1 Then
                    response.write("Greater than 1")
                else
                    response.write("Not!")
                End If
```