# How does an 'if' statement work in a markup file?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063456/939213) works  . But why?

```
<% if (condition) { %> some html <% } %>
```

I would expect it to either have no effect, or simply throw an exception because each part is not valid C#, and nor is the whole of it.

Comment: This is slightly off-topic, but Phil Haack has a good quick reference guide for the syntax of various of these constructions. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the page is compiled, the markup is turned into commands that will output the HTML to the response stream. Basically the code becomes:

```
Response.Write("The HTML code before");
if (condition) {
  Response.Write(" some html ");
}
Response.Write("The HTML code after");
```

The example where you mix code and markup (`<% int i = %>3<% ;%>`) would become:

```
Response.Write("The HTML code before");
int i =
Response.Write("3");
;
Response.Write("The HTML code after");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the clearest explanation I've ever read of this subject.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't exlain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The official name given to <% is "server-side scripting delimiters" or "ASP.NET inline expressions". also called Asp.net server side scripting. Microsoft guys call them "code nuggets" in their blogs or workplace.

`<% %>`

```
is for inclusion of server-side code to the Render() method 
(<% x = x + 1; %>) of the generated class.
```

**When compiler(.net framework compiler at server side for asp.net) executes this code it performs  the operation  specified in it. And generated output is rendered into simple HTML form, that could be rendered onto the web browser(that you see if prefixed by eval).**

they are basically used to let you write server side execution code inside your presentational logic(aspx). example: sessions, debug printing, userName etc. although visual studio IDE has pretty good replacement of them using their own UI controls.