# How to write if else condition inside a aspx page (i.e) Inside the HTML code?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to display a particular part of sentence for two different condition, how can I write a `if`  `else` statement inside the .aspx page to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide code what you have tried. Check this as ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063436/if-statement-in-aspx-page

Comment: What is unclear about the answers you find when you type [aspx if else](https://www.google.nl/search?q=aspx+if+else&oq=aspx+if+else&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2662j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) into Google? The top three results all are from stack overflow, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose server code with `<% %>` on your .ASPX page:

```
<% if(condition) { %>
    sentence one
<% } else { %>
    sentence two
<% } %>
```