# How to use IF statements on EVAL Listview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm using a listview which it's using Mysql as datasource. On Mysql I have a field named "Master" which only has a "1" or a "0". i want that when the binding happens, if the field contains a 1 it is replace with a tick, if its a 0, replace it with an x. these labels are hrefs too so i can click on them and change to its opposite value (at least that's what i want to accomplished here)

I'm using the following code to test the IF statement:

```
                <td> 
                    <asp:Label  
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Master").ToString() == "1" ? "a" : "b"
                                %>'> 
                    </asp:Label> 
                </td>
```

So far it does the job. But when instead of an "a" or a "b" I replace it with html code, an error shows up:

> Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>   Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well
>   formed.

this is the code I'm trying to use:

```
               <td> 
                    <asp:Label  
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Master").ToString() == "1" ? 
"<a href='#' style='color:#269302; font-size:25px;'><i class='fas fa-check'></i></a>" : 
"<a href='#' style='color:#bf2727; font-size:25px;'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></a>"
                                    %>'> 
                        </asp:Label> 
                    </td>
```

Can someone please explain why using html tags inside this code is showing me an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If statement in aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063436/if-statement-in-aspx-page)

Answer (score 0):

if someone has the same problem as me, I found the solution!

instead of using an If statement inline, I use a function in the code-behind.

this is how it looks like on my .aspx page:

```
          <asp:Label  
              runat="server" 
              Text='<%# ConvertIcon(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Master")))%>'>
          </asp:Label>
```

ConvertIcon is the name of my function. this is what it looks like on my .aspx.cs page:

```
    protected string ConvertIcon(Nullable<int> binarydata)
{
    string labelText = string.Empty;
    if (binarydata == 1)
        labelText = "<a href='#' style='color:#269302; font-size:25px;'><i class='fas fa-check'></i></a>";
        else
        labelText = "<a href='#' style='color:#bf2727; font-size:25px;'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></a>";
    return labelText;
}
```