# How can i hide list when no record?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have this code to display a list but need your help to hide when the list have to no record?.

Need your help hiding inside list when no record?

```
<ul id="treeview">
          @foreach (var item in rpInfo)
             {
              <li data-expanded="true" class="panel-handler" data-id="@item.ID">
                <i class="far fa-check-circle" data-id="@item.Flag" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>@item.CompnayName(@item.Type)
                    <ul>
                       <li data-expanded="true">  <i class="far fa-check-circle" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i> @item.Name (@item.Type)</li>
                      </ul>
              </li>
              }
  </ul>
```

this section need to be hidden when no record

```
<li data-expanded="true">  <i class="far fa-check-circle" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i> @item.Name (@item.Type)</li>
```

Here is how it's displayed when no record. it only display the icon
[Here is how it look when no record - i want to hide highlighted one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXkoh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add `if-else`, more: [If statement in aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063436/if-statement-in-aspx-page/3063456)

```
<% if(somecondition) { %>
   some html
<% } %>
```

Yours:

```
<% @if(item.CompnayName(@item.Type) != "") { %>
   <li data-expanded="true" class="panel-handler" data-id="@item.ID">
                <i class="far fa-check-circle" data-id="@item.Flag" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>@item.CompnayName(@item.Type)
                    <ul>
                       <li data-expanded="true">  <i class="far fa-check-circle" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i> @item.Name (@item.Type)</li>
                      </ul>
              </li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: i'm on razor asp.net core this giving me error companyname @item.CompnayName(@item.Type) cannot be used as a method

Comment: please check out syntax.

`@if (value % 2 == 0)
{
    <p>The value was even.</p>
}`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you! I checked the link but my question is `@item.CompnayName(@item.Type` .net complaining that `CompnayName` is not a method

Comment: I dont know ur json/pojo structure.