# Is there an easy way to only execute an if statement if approached from a certain html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a shared JS file that has to include an append for three files that should only load when approached from a certain HTML file.

Let's say there's index1 and index2. Index1 is our current homepage but it's kind of old and outdated, so I want to make a new home. But I want people to be able to reach the old home too. They share a default.aspx file that basically gives them the same building blocks. They also share a home.js.

I want to include additional files to index2 through a statement like this:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme1.css"  id="themeCss" type="text/css" />');
```

Is there an easy way to make sure it only loads when opened from index2 through an if statement? Maybe through knockout or something?

Comment: why don't you do all this on the server? Determine wether index1 or index2 is requested and based on that change the content of the returned file, like `include additional files to index2 through a statement like this:` [If statement in aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063436/if-statement-in-aspx-page)

Answer (score 0):

If there is id for the view model element in index2 page, then you can use

> `ko.dataFor(document.getElementById(id))

to check if binding has been applied to the`page element. If applied then append else leave as is. This is one way there are multiple ways to check.